# Should I use a lock on resources in a listener node with multiple callbacks?

Tags: ros, multi-thread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I have a node which listens to multiple topics & has a callback for each topic, should I need locks/mutexes on the resources that are changed by more than one callback? My question stems from whether or not callback functions are executed in new threads--could code be concurrently executing in two different callback functions at once?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48429/should-i-use-a-lock-on-resources-in-a-listener-node-with-multiple-callbacks?/) by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-11-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer depends on the number of spin loops you are running. Have a look at [this page](http://ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).

The short answer is: if you call `spin` only once in your applications, you shouldn't need to synchronize. If you have multiple spinners, synchronize.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-11-16**:
...anf if it's C++ (was not clear in the original question). rospy uses one thread per callback by default.

**Comment by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on 2013-01-20**:
I was writing my node in python. I wasn't aware of the difference in handlers between python and C++. Thanks!